# Laravel Fortify Route Prefix

Tags: php, laravel, fortify

I want to set `admin` prefix to all laravel fortify routes.

Prior to `8.*`, putting `Auth::routes()` inside route `admin` prefix group works fine. Since I don't want to use `laravel/ui` in my `8.*` application, I eager to know how can I add prefix in fortify routes.

I added that line in `fortify.php`:

```
'prefix' => 'admin'
```

But that didn't work. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. In your `config\fortify.php` file:

Replace

```
'prefix' => 'admin'
```

with

```
'path' => 'admin'
```

Confirm it has worked using the console command `php artisan route:list`. You might need to clear your cached routes afterwards.

Comment: I use Laravel 10. this solution works for all routes related to Jetstream except user/profile